# Stuggling with SMTP for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I have a laravel project uploaded on shared hosting via Go Daddy. I find that it's very 'moody, it often stops working.

Often i get time out errors and the erorr below

```
[2018-07-07n23:22:01] local.ERROR: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "me@ne.org" using 2 possible authenticators {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username \"x@x.x\" using 2 possible authenticators
```

I have tried using external smtp services such as mail chip or mailjet and also get errors.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=sdasda
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

I have even purchased outlook from Godaddy to try solve the issue and not rely on cpanel email.

Could this be becuase i have basic hosting and not business hosting?

Comment: I recommend you contact Godaddy support about this. It could be that you have reached your email quota, the SMTP server could be down, there could be a network error. In any case this question is off-topic here.

Comment: I believe the problem is with your outlook account. i had this issue with the google account (like less secure app acess turned off). You can create an email from the cpanel, use the godaddy smtp settings to check everything is good or not.